# PHP - External Login Script Redirection Issue

Tags: php, authentication, directory, subdomain, vbulletin

I'm having an issue with using this external login script for VBulletin.
I have a subdomain which holds the forums under "**forum.blacklist-rs.com**"
and the external script runs on the root directory "**public_html**".

I'm attempting to make a successful login through this script on the root directory, but unfortunately every time i login the scripts includes my main domain first like as follows:
**blacklist-rs.com/forum.blacklist-rs.com/login.php?=**

If anyone could assist me in finding a solution that would be great thankyou!

The script is as follows

```
<?php
$curdir = getcwd();
chdir('/home/blackli1/forum.blacklist-rs.com');
require_once('/home/blackli1/forum.blacklist-rs.com/global.php');
chdir($curdir);
if ($vbulletin->userinfo['userid'] == 0) {
  echo "<form id=\"login\" action=\"forum.blacklist-rs.com/login.php?do=login\" method=\"post\" onsubmit=\"md5hash(vb_login_password, vb_login_md5password, vb_login_md5password_utf, 0)\">
<script type=\"text/javascript\" src=\"forum.blacklist-rs.com/clientscript/vbulletin_md5.js?v=364\"></script>
<a href=\"forum.blacklist-rs.com/register.php\">Register</a>
<label for=\"navbar_username\">Username</label>
<input type=\"text\" class=\"bginput\" style=\"font-size: 11px\" name=\"vb_login_username\" id=\"navbar_username\" size=\"10\" accesskey=\"u\" tabindex=\"101\" onfocus=\"if (this.value == 'User Name') this.value = '';\" />
<label for=\"navbar_password\">Password</label>
<input type=\"password\" class=\"bginput\" style=\"font-size: 11px\" name=\"vb_login_password\" id=\"navbar_password\" size=\"10\" tabindex=\"102\" />
<label for=\"cb_cookieuser_navbar\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"cookieuser\" value=\"1\" tabindex=\"103\" id=\"cb_cookieuser_navbar\" accesskey=\"c\" />Remember Me?</label>
<input type=\"submit\" class=\"button\" value=\"Login\" tabindex=\"104\" title=\"Enter your username and password in the boxes provided to login, or click the 'register' button to create a profile for yourself.\" accesskey=\"s\" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, When i do this
it just directs to the page to http://blacklist-rs.com/login.php?do=login

Comment: Is it true that you can accessing this script thru a web browser ?

Comment: Yeah you are able to, Rather then accessing it through a subdomain it does it through a forward slash directory
example

blacklist-rs.com/forums/login.php?do=login

this would work.